# i18n translation in a form

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I'm trying to make a create a form with i18n translation.

I already tried that but it's not working :

```
<div id="form" align="center"
      justify="center">

<v-col sm="4" align="center"
      justify="center">
  <v-form
    ref="form"
    v-model="valid"
    lazy-validation
  >
    <v-text-field
      v-model="login"
      label="{{ $t('Username') }}"
      required
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-text-field
      v-model="password"
      label="{{ $t('Password') }}"
      type="password"
      required
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-btn
      color=blue
      class="mr-4"
      @click="validate"
    >
      {{ $t('Login') }}
    </v-btn>

  </v-form>
  </v-col>
</div>
```

Do someone have any idea to translate the labels on my form ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like `:label="$t('your.translation.key')"`